Csp whitelisting in magento2.4.7-p3
In Checkout Page, I cant clear the csp console error:

How can I resolve these console errors using the csp_whitelist.xml file?
I have added csp_whitelist.xml file in custom module and added the domains, but still getting error in checkout page.May I know how to whitelist csp using noce and hash?

You can create app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/etc/csp_whitelist.xml with following content:
Note: Below values just sample value, You need to put actual domain names.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp:etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
        <policies>
            <policy id="script-src">
                <values>
                    <value id="adobedtm" type="host">assets.adobedtm.com</value>
                    <value id="adobe" type="host">*.adobe.com</value>
                </values>
            </policy>
        </policies>
</csp_whitelist>

Also additional you can use following policy id if require:
<policy id="style-src">
<policy id="img-src">
<policy id="connect-src">
<policy id="media-src">


I have trieed it. But Still getting error in checkout page. Would you please help me in csp whitelisting using nonce and hash values

@Preethi As I mentioned in Answer, You need to update domains as per error you are seeing.. i just added sample domain for whitelist

this is not directly a CSP issue, here your problem is not just about allowing a different domain name to use a script on your application, it's about allowing inline scripts from files, which is no longer allowed. I already jumped into the issue sooner : APSB24-40 Security Patch: CSP and Checkout Updates
But no answer were provided.
As per my understanding, following magento guidelines should work.
What you need to do is to add a "nonce" to the file to allow things to work. Hopefully Magento prepared prebuilt methods who do the job themselves...but you still have to go for a very annoying process to check about all the potential checkout files errors and whitelist things by yourself.
These methods are defined in
\Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer
You will have to handle this way, all files were you have script tags inside phtml inside your checkout. I will provide you some screenshot of the modification as I feel it's gonna be more explicit this way to understand what are the changes.
Here comes an example to render the tag itself

There is an other point of attention which is events listenner as per example

EDIT : As per my understanding I haven't been hable to get rid of errors from GTM in the checkout; as in reality GTM is a dynamic script modifying itself and the google doc about it doesn't seem to be working. Although, handling the file the same as others seems to make things work even if the message remains. But yeah, be carefull if you have things like GTM cause this can be extra tricky additionnal time.
